# Помогите с добавить значения в массив

Tags: jquery

Не получается добавить значение в массив, что делаю не так?

```js
    var sd = $('#SD').val();
    var fi = $('#FI').val();
    var copa = $('#COPA').val();
    var mm = $('#MM').val();
    var sm = $('#SM').val();
    var cc = $('#CC').val();
    
    var autoArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < autoArray; i++){
   autoArray.push(sd,fi,copa,mm,sm,cc);
}
console.log (autoArray);
```

Comment: `i < autoArray` сравниваете переменную с пустым массивом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл не к чему там:

```
    var sd = $('#SD').val();
    var fi = $('#FI').val();
    var copa = $('#COPA').val();
    var mm = $('#MM').val();
    var sm = $('#SM').val();
    var cc = $('#CC').val();

    var autoArray = [];
    autoArray.push(sd,fi,copa,mm,sm,cc);
    console.log (autoArray);
```

Comment: Спасибо, только начинаю с массивами работать ))

Answer (score 2):

```
var autoArray = [
    $('#SD').val(),
    $('#FI').val(),
    $('#COPA').val(),
    $('#MM').val(),
    $('#SM').val(),
    $('#CC').val(),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам в таком виде включения данных цикл вообще не нужен

```js
    var sd = "10";
    var fi = "10";
    var copa = "10";
    var mm = "10";
    var sm = "10";
    var cc = "10";
    
    var autoArray = [sd,fi,copa,mm,sm,cc];
console.log (autoArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var vars = ["sd", "fi", "copa", "mm", "sm", "cc"];
 var autoArray = [];
 $.each(vars, function(key, val) {
  window[val] = $('#' + val.toUpperCase()).val();
  autoArray.push(window[val]);
 });
 console.log(autoArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```